# Loop through .txt files and convert them to .csv files. Then zip them?

Tags: powershell

I've got 3 `.txt` files that I need to convert to `.csv`.  The below seems to work, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner/more efficient way to do this?

```
$files = @("C:\AllAcctsLog.txt", "C:\WithAcctsLog.txt", "C:\WithoutAcctsLog.txt")

foreach($file in $files){
    $filePath = Join-Path ([System.IO.FileInfo]$file).DirectoryName ([System.IO.FileInfo]$file).BaseName
    Import-Csv $file -Delimiter ';' -Header (1..12) | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | select -Skip 1 |
    Set-Content ($filePath + '.csv')
}
```

I also need to zip these 3 `.csv` files, but I'm not sure how to do that with my current implementation.  Should I be placing these new `.csv` files into an array as they're created and then zip the array?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could probably make it more efficient using string methods to simply reformat the lines, but it's going to get messy if you have to allow for the possibility of a data field containing an embedded delimiter character.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
$files = @("C:\AllAcctsLog.txt", "C:\WithAcctsLog.txt", "C:\WithoutAcctsLog.txt");

$outputFiles = @();
$archiveName = '"C:\archive.zip"';
$7Zip = 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe';

foreach($file in $files){
    $filePath = Join-Path ([System.IO.FileInfo]$file).DirectoryName (([System.IO.FileInfo]$file).BaseName + '.csv');
    $outputFiles += "`"$filePath`"";
    Import-Csv $file -Delimiter ';' -Header (1..12) | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | select -Skip 1 |
    Set-Content $filePath;
}

$outputFiles = $outputFiles -join ' ';

&$7Zip a $archiveName $outputFiles
```

Note that I changed how `$filePath` is defined.

Comment: I see the `a` referenced a lot (last line).  What does that mean?

Comment: @Chris That tells 7-Zip what mode you're running in.  It means "Add files to archive".  See `7z.exe -?` or the Command Line Version section of the 7-Zip help file.